RabbitMQ-based messaging with long-running consumer process - I need a better pattern
I have a service that consumes messages from RabbitMQ queue. Its main characteristic is the long-running handler, the processing can take anything from 5 minutes to 6 hours (in fact, no real limitation, importantly, it is often longer than RabbitMQ's recommended and default ack timeout of 30 minutes). So, in order to avoid acknowledgement timeout, my current pattern is:

receive message
pause consumption of messages
acknowledge received message
run process
resume consumption

This is implemented in a .net application, with RabbitMQ.Client library (the official library).
A big downside to this pattern is that I have to acknowledge the message before the work is done. If something happens (service dies before finishing for whatever reason), there is no result and no more message. A naive solution would be to set a gigantic timeout, like 2 days, and implement ACKing after the work is finished. But then, again, if something happens before the acknowledgement, the message isn't requeued before the timeout expires, and 2 days is a long time to wait. So, ideally, we would want a short, but extendable timeout. So that we could

receive
start working, while periodically saying "not ACKing yet, but please extend the timeout"
ACK once finished

This way, if the service dies and doesn't "extend the lease", the message is requeued after the (short, like, 10 minutes) timeout has expired - and, for example, the next attempt is made.
The one thing missing is such "please extend my lease" API. Or am I missing something? Please in any case share your thoughts on this.

can you ignore the timeout, do whatever processing needs to be done , if timed-out -> re-request the message (check nothing has changed from the initial),  post the result ?  ... obviously a bit of housekeeping needed to manage  .... NB:assuming this is single threaded.

Timeout in this case is RabbitMQ's mechanism, not the client's. If time elapsed between delivery and acknowledgement exceeds timeout, the message is re-delivered to the queue. (At least, it's my understanding). I do not want to get rid of that, since the service isn't guaranteed to survive long enough to acknowledge.

I am new with rabbitmq myself, but doesn't rabbitmq have heartbeat to check if a consumer is still connected to it and is still doing the job? Even if we have longer message ttl, rabbitmq won't wait for say 2 days to requeue it if the service dies. It will immediately requeue it to the next available consumer. Also we can set max retries to a message so it doesn't poison the queue. You can check on Quorum queues and dead lettering.

Thank you, will do some additional research!

So, it looks like RabbitMQ does not have "leasing" of messages. I don't know if any other messaging bus system does, but it isn't a matter of discussion this time, let's say we can't switch the message bus at this time, anyway.
So, my plan to improve this situation is to create an additional service - like a leasing manager, with its own persistant storage. The handling will look like this, then:

Long-running service A receives a single message from RabbitMQ queue

It pauses receiving messages (until the work is done)

It packs together message's payload, some headers that we use in messages, requeue destination (will be the queue from which we just received in most cases) and lease timeout and sends this package to the lease manager service LM.

The lease timeout should be compatible with how often service A is able to
emit a heartbeat message


Service A ACKs the message to RabbitMQ

Service A stars working on the task

Service A periodically emits the "still working" heartbeat message to LM.

When done with the work, Service A sends a message to LM with a command to finish the lease and dispose of the message

Service A "opens for business" again - starts listening to the task messages.

LM, upon receiving of the first registration of the message persists it into the storage and ACKs the message (this should be a quick operation, as all others that LM does)

LM, upon receiving the heartbeat message, looks up the persisted original message and extends its lease by the lease timeout value (updates the storage with the new timestamp (current time + lease timeout))

Upon receiving "work completed" message, looks up the original message and deletes it from storage

LM also has a scheduled task, in which it looks up all the original messages  with expired lease, re-queues them to the provided queues and removes them from the storage. Actually, probably removes, makes sure removal worked and then re-queues, otherwise some malfunction here causes a small tragedy.


Not too complex, but still rather many moving parts, actually. This design is still work in progress. If I can simplify it, I would.

It is complex when you start thinking about scale, visibility, troubleshooting, etc. I think you underestimate the effort needed to create a production-quality service like this.

Consider using a separate subsystem to process the long-running task. For example, temporal.io supports tasks of unlimited duration with a heartbeat.

This for sure looks interesting - thanks! However at this time we're looking only for a possible improvement of how our existing systems interact with the message bus. I.e., we're not considering any major rewrite or porting of services to any new framework. Which is why I am focusing on timeouts in RabbitMQ and possibilities around working with those in a more sophisticated way.

I don't think you can implement your requirements relying only on RabbitMQ. You will have to track the state of the long-running task somewhere else.

I sort of landed on the same, as well. I will try to describe the plan in a separate "answer" post here.

I'm not sure why you want to reinvent the wheel instead of using an industry-proven solution that solves your problem out of the box and has tons of additional benefits.

Maybe if you enrich your answer on how exactly this tool may be applicable to this case and not only self-promote your company, it would be more convincable.

Temporal is an open-source project under the MIT License. A long-running activity is a function that can take as long as needed (months), assuming it periodically heartbeats.
